# @DataJpaTest doesn't read spring.jpa.* properties while @SpringBootTest does

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE, and configured `src/test/resources/application.yml` to be

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
      ddl-auto: none
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
      properties:
        hibernate:
          generate_statistics: false
          show_sql: false
```

I have a very simple test:

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class MyTest {
  ...
}
```

The test ignores the properties (can be easily seen as it prints the hibernate statements). Putting the same properties in a `application.properties` file is working.

Changing the name to `application-test.yml` and running on profile test didn't help either.

When changing the `@DataJpaTest` annotation to `@SpringBootTest` it's working...

It's important to note that **the rest of the properties (things related to my application specifically and are not with `spring.*` prefix are being read and used normally**

I do prefer to use a yaml file (like in `/src/main/resources`) and rather not load a complete `@SpringBootTest` just for pure JPA tests... Is there anything else that I can configure for this to work?

Comment: for me its printing jpa sql statements and not reading the flags, super annoying!

Comment: Try to add: 
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.yaml")

Answer (score 1):

@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE) - This causes the DataJpaTest to use the same configuration as Spring Boot Main.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of indentation. `properties` has to be moved one level to the left.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
      ddl-auto: none
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    properties:
      hibernate:
        generate_statistics: false
        show_sql: false
```

But you could also try this if you use logback.xml for logging config:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.stat" level="OFF"/>
```